# integrating hazelcast management centre alerts with Pagerduty

Tags: linux, hazelcast

Is it possible to integrate hazelcast management centre alerts with Pagerduty? Also what is the best possible mechanism that can be implemented for monitoring hazelcast and trigger an alert when an incident occurs

Thank,

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast Management Center will provide [alert notifications mechanism](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6-EA2/manual/html-single/index.html#creating-alerts) as of [3.6](http://hazelcast.org/download/). You can create alerts to be notified based on some criteria via mail.

You can also use [JMX](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#monitoring-with-jmx) to monitor hazelcast cluster via your own preferred incident management system which supports JMX

Comment: Mesut. Thanks for the update, but 3.6 is not the stable version right? As per the doc it is a development release. So I think it is not advisable to use it in production.

Comment: Current Hazelcast Early Access Release for 3.6 is 3.6-EA2. Hazelcast Early Access Releases are not meant to be used in production. I think you can test 3.6-EA2 for now and use 3.6 when it is released. 3.6 release is expected in December.

Comment: Thanks for your update Mesut. In that case what is the best way to configure alerts on parameters related to Hazelcast, like cluster status etc.

Comment: here you can find everything regarding JMX per Node. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#jmx-api-per-node
Hazelcast Enterprise offers Clustered JMX feature through Management Center. http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#clustered-jmx . You can also find how to do integration with well known incident management systems in the doc.